# tox errors when running nova openstack unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, openstack, openstack-nova, tox

I am trying to run openstack unit tests, and i'm having trouble with tox 
i've been following this [tutorial](https://docs.openstack.org/zun/latest/contributor/unit-tests.html)
i have started with a brand new Ubuntu16.04 LTS instance which has `python 2.7` and `python 3.5`
i took the exact same instructions as the tutorial, the only difference is that i clone the `nova` repository instead of `zun` :
`git clone https://github.com/openstack/nova`

and i keep getting this error :

```
ERROR: invocation failed (exit code 1), logfile: /home/mnm13/nova/.tox/py35/log/py35-1.log
ERROR: actionid: py35 
msg: getenv cmdargs: ['/home/mnm13/nova/.tox/py35/bin/pip', 'install', 
    '-chttps://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/requirements/plain/upper-constraints.txt',
    '-r/home/mnm13/nova/test-requirements.txt']
```

you can find the log file [here](https://github.com/MheniMerz/tmp-logfile/blob/master/py35-1.log)
Any one had this before?
thank you.

Comment: You should go [here](https://ask.openstack.org/en/help/) for OpenStack help. You might find something related to this there.

Comment: thank you i posted the question over there too, but i think this i more related to python and tox

Comment: What is in the logfile `/home/mnm13/nova/.tox/py35/log/py35-1.log`?

Comment: Activate the virtual env: `source /home/mnm13/nova/.tox/py35/bin/activate` and try the command `/home/mnm13/nova/.tox/py35/bin/pip install -chttps://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/requirements/plain/upper-constraints.txt -r/home/mnm13/nova/test-requirements.txt`. What is the error? [edit] the question and add the details.

Comment: @phd thank you for your reply, i have tried to run the `pip install` command in the virtual environment but it didn't work. also i have uploaded the log-file  to a github [repo] (https://github.com/MheniMerz/tmp-logfile/blob/master/py35-1.log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Building wheels for collected packages: python-pcre
…
 src/pcremodule.c:32:18: fatal error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
```

The error is quite obvious: to compile `python-pcre` you need sources for `pcre` library. `python-pcre` is just a Python wrapper for [`pcre`](http://www.pcre.org/) which is written in C.

Comment: i had to install pcre  `sudo apt-get install libpcre3`  `sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev`  thank you this solved the problem. i would up-vote the answer if i had enough reputation points :)